# Check Form Before Submit Use Ajax Django

Tags: ajax, onsubmit

I use Ajax to send data from form to server. But I want to check data in form before Submit by Ajax:

```
<form id='#id_form' onsubmit='return checkInputSubmit();' >
...
</form>
```

In Ajax:

```
$('#id_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#id_form').serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.result == true) {
                    //My code
                }
                else {
                    //My code
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

But checkInputSubmit() can't prevent submit from Ajax. You can explain for me and give me solution to check data in form before Submit by Ajax. 
Thanks.

Comment: You could do the check in the `submit` handler instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Blurp, I found the solution by use your help.

```
 $('#id_form').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#id_form').serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.result == true) {
                    //My code
                }
                else {
                    //My code
                }
            }
        });
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

in the `$('#id_form').submit(function(e)` event, you can check/edit/return... any thing you want before call Ajax. Within Ajax, i think it won't work and don't good. (we just check ajax result, not input)